# How to dispatch click event in Android

Tags: java, android, events, click, dispatch

I have a custom navigation bar that contains a button, I would dispatch the click event so that the activity that contains my *navigation* bar can respond to *click*

```
    public class BarrePersonnalisee extends LinearLayout implements OnClickListener {
        Context mycontext;
        View convertview;
        ImageButton searchadresse;

        public BarrePersonnalisee(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
            mycontext=context;
            convertview=LayoutInflater.from(mycontext).inflate(R.layout.barre, this);
            searchadresse=(ImageButton)convertview.findViewById(R.id.searchadresse);
            searchadresse.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            switch (arg0.getId()) {
            case R.id.searchadresse:
                //I want to dispatch this event
                    break;
                   }
            }
    ....
    }

public class TaxiMapActivity extends MapActivity{

    BarrePersonnalisee barre;

    ...
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        barre=(BarrePersonnalisee)this.findViewById(R.id.barre1);
        //task to do here


}
```

can anyone help?

Comment: Not getting exactly, can you please elaborate it?

Comment: use setOnClickListener() method

Comment: The navigation bar is a custom class that extends the LinearLayout, so I can integrate anywhere in my application as a simple view.
I have an activity that contains the bar, and I am looking for a way to dispatch the click on the button to execute some tasks on my activity as if it was the listener of this event.
(sorry I'm not a good as that in English) ^^

Answer (score 3):

I believe what you are looking for is `button.performClick()`

and if you don't want the click sound, you can do:

```
button.setSoundEffectsEnabled(false)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use EventBus here: http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/

1. Load the EventBus

   dependencies {
         compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
         testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
         compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
         compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1'
         compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
   }
2. Create new Event type Class. Let's call it BarrePersonnaliseeEvent.

> public class BarrePersonnaliseeEvent {
>
> ```
> private boolean _touchDown;
> public BarrePersonnaliseeEvent(boolean touchDown) {
>     _touchDown = touchDown;
> }
>
> public boolean isTouchDown(){
>     return _touchDown;
> } }
> ```

2. Now pass the event to the EventBus

public class BarrePersonnalisee extends LinearLayout implements OnClickListener {
        Context mycontext;
        View convertview;
        ImageButton searchadresse;

```
    public BarrePersonnalisee(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mycontext=context;
        convertview=LayoutInflater.from(mycontext).inflate(R.layout.barre, this);
        searchadresse=(ImageButton)convertview.findViewById(R.id.searchadresse);
        searchadresse.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        switch (arg0.getId()) {
        case R.id.searchadresse:
            //I want to dispatch this event
                EventBus.getDefault().post(new BarrePersonnaliseeEvent(true));
                break;
               }
        }
....
}
```

3. Update Activity to start receiving events:

public class TaxiMapActivity extends MapActivity{

```
BarrePersonnalisee barre;

...
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    barre=(BarrePersonnalisee)this.findViewById(R.id.barre1);

}
```

@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
    public void onBarrePersonnaliseeEvent(BarrePersonnaliseeEvent event) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Button touched: " + event.isTouchDown(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}

4. Make sure to register and unregister for EventBus in your Activity

   @Override
   public void onStart(Context context) {
       super.onStart(context);
       EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
   }

   @Override
   public void onStop() {
       super.onStop();
       EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
   }

Answer (score -1):

Use this code

```
            Button b=new Button(this);
            b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //what you want to do
            }
        })
```

Comment: The navigation bar is a custom class that extends the LinearLayout, so I can integrate anywhere in my application as a simple view. I have an activity that contains the bar, and I am looking for a way to dispatch the click on the button to execute some tasks on my activity as if it was the listener of this event. (sorry I'm not a good as that in English) ^^

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that you need to attach click event to a button inside your navigation bar, you can use `setOnClickListener()` method, and implements the `onClick()` method, for example:

```
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //define what you want to do here
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Works", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

that will show a toast saying "Works" when you click the button.

Comment: I need to execut tasks that exist in my activity not in my bar.